# Alias, или symlink в apache

Tags: apache, alias, symlinks

Есть сайт в `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site`. Он – копия того, что лежит в `/opt/site`. Чтобы вручную их не синхронизировать, я хочу перенаправить **system.domain/site** в `/opt/site`. Сделал symlink:

```
ln -s /opt/site site2
```

Но при обращении в браузере к **system.domain.com/site2**, я вижу чистый белый лист. Если я делаю symlink на папку,

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site_copy symlink
```

то при обращении к **system.domain.com/symlink** страница грузится, что даёт понять, что symlink'и работают. А дело скорее всего в правах.

Я пробовал дописать в `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site/.htaccess`

```
<Directory /opt/site>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Тоже – белый лист.

**/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
#RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>

Options FollowSymLinks -- я добавил
```

Comment: Вам нужна директива Options, по умолчанию она блочит симлинки

Answer (score 1):

вам нужна директива [options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options), которая может встречаться в: `server config`, `virtual host`, `directory`, `.htaccess`.

в частности, следует указать такую опцию:

```
options followsymlinks
```

Comment: Если я перехожу по симлинку в директорию /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site_copy не значит ли это что эта опция унаследована от конфигов выше?

Comment: да, явно где-то в конфигурации переопределено стандартное поведение: **не** следовать симлинкам.

Comment: Почему тогда он следует симлинку если он ссылается в /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/system/httpdocs/site_copy ?

Comment: «я перехожу», «он следует» — это вы про браузер клиента, в котором делаются запросы к вашему сайту?

Comment: Да, конечно про браузер. Симлинк когда на одно место ведёт то работает, когда на другое -- нет.

В вопросе добавил содержимое .htaccess. Опция фолловсимлинкс добавляется.

Comment: Всё, разобрался, нашёл httpd.include для system субдомена, и в него добавил Алиас, затем сделал reload httpd